# direnv and environment variables

Tags: bash, python, fish

I'm trying to get autoactivation of conda/mamba environments working using direnv but I'm running across a problem that seems to be due to my lack of understanding of how bash scripts work with environment variables.

My shell is fish but direnv is bash based.  I don't think my shell being fish has any bearing on the problem since I run the appropriate direnv hook for fish.

My `.direnvrc` file is as follows:

```
layout_mamba() {
  local MAMBA_EXE="${HOME}/bin/micromamba" # Make sure this points to path of your micromamba executable
  # initialize micromamba
  eval "$(${MAMBA_EXE} shell hook --shell=bash)"
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    # Explicit environment name from layout command.
    local env_name="$1"
    micromamba activate ${env_name}
  elif (grep -q name: environment.yml); then
    # Detect environment name from `environment.yml` file in `.envrc` directory
    micromamba activate `grep name: environment.yml | sed -e 's/name: //'`
  else
    (>&2 echo No environment specified);
    exit 1;
  fi;
}
```

And it works as is but notice that in my `eval` statement, I use the value of `$MAMBA_EXE` but the remaining calls `micromamba` directly.  Everything that I've tried for substituting $MAMBA_EXE for micromamba has failed.

Any suggestions for making my `.direnvrc` more general?

**Edit:** For example, if I change line 8 from `micromamba activate ${env_name}` to `${MAMBA_EXE} activate ${env_name}` I get:

```
direnv: loading ~/test-env/.envrc

'micromamba' is running as a subprocess and can't modify the parent shell.
Thus you must initialize your shell before using activate and deactivate.

    To initialize the current bash shell, run:
        $ eval "$(micromamba shell hook --shell=bash)"
    and then activate or deactivate with:
        $ micromamba activate
    
To automatically initialize all future (bash) shells, run:
    $ micromamba shell init --shell=bash --prefix=~/micromamba

Supported shells are {bash, zsh, csh, xonsh, cmd.exe, powershell, fish}.

critical libmamba Shell not initialized
```

Fish won't let me run `${MAMBA_EXE} shell hook --shell=bash` but running `$MAMBA_EXE shell hook --shell=bash` produces:

```
# Copyright (C) 2012 Anaconda, Inc
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause

__mamba_exe() (
    "$MAMBA_EXE" "$@"
)

__mamba_hashr() {
    if [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION:+x}" ]; then
        \rehash
    elif [ -n "${POSH_VERSION:+x}" ]; then
        :  # pass
    else
        \hash -r
    fi
}

__mamba_activate() {
    \local ask_conda
    ask_conda="$(PS1="${PS1:-}" __mamba_exe shell --shell bash "$@")" || \return
    \eval "$ask_conda"
    __mamba_hashr
}

__mamba_reactivate() {
    \local ask_conda
    ask_conda="$(PS1="${PS1:-}" __mamba_exe shell --shell bash reactivate)" || \return
    \eval "$ask_conda"
    __mamba_hashr
}

micromamba() {
    \local cmd="${1-__missing__}"
    case "$cmd" in
        activate|deactivate)
            __mamba_activate "$@"
            ;;
        install|update|upgrade|remove|uninstall)
            __mamba_exe "$@" || \return
            __mamba_reactivate
            ;;
        self-update)
            __mamba_exe "$@" || \return

            # remove leftover backup file on Windows
            if [ -f "$MAMBA_EXE.bkup" ]; then
                rm -f $MAMBA_EXE.bkup
            fi
            ;;
        *)
            __mamba_exe "$@"
            ;;
    esac
}

if [ -z "${CONDA_SHLVL+x}" ]; then
    \export CONDA_SHLVL=0
    # In dev-mode MAMBA_EXE is python.exe and on Windows
    # it is in a different relative location to condabin.
    if [ -n "${_CE_CONDA+x}" ] && [ -n "${WINDIR+x}" ]; then
        PATH="${MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX}/condabin:${PATH}"
    else
        PATH="${MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX}/condabin:${PATH}"
    fi
    \export PATH

    # We're not allowing PS1 to be unbound. It must at least be set.
    # However, we're not exporting it, which can cause problems when starting a second shell
    # via a first shell (i.e. starting zsh from bash).
    if [ -z "${PS1+x}" ]; then
        PS1=
    fi
fi

if [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION:+x}" ]; then
  if ! command -v compinit > /dev/null; then
    autoload -U +X compinit && if [[ "${ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX-}" = true ]]; then
      compinit -u
    else
      compinit
    fi
  fi
  autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit

  _umamba_zsh_completions()
  {
    COMPREPLY=($(__mamba_exe completer "${(@s: :)${(@s: :)COMP_LINE}:1}"))
  }

  complete -o default -F _umamba_zsh_completions micromamba
fi
if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION:+x}" ]; then
  _umamba_bash_completions()
  {
    COMPREPLY=($(__mamba_exe completer "${COMP_WORDS[@]:1}"))
  }
  complete -o default -F _umamba_bash_completions micromamba
fi
```

Comment: Suggestions? Yeah: Any time you write "everything I tried has failed" when asking people for help, it helps to go back and show at least some of those things you have tried, and what went wrong with each of them. It in people not having to suggest the same things again, and you in not having to read suggestions of the same things you've already tried. Also, I'm not exactly sure what is you're trying to achieve here? `${HOME}/bin` isn't in `$PATH` and you have to give the full path manually when running it? Except that you say it works in both cases, so...?

Comment: Another thing to look at is what `${MAMBA_EXE} shell hook --shell=bash` outputs. That `eval` command would run that output in the shell, so if it e.g. prints a modified `PATH`, that would take effect there.

Comment: Added an example of something I've tried as well as the output (from within a fish shell) of the output from the shell hook command.

Comment: Right, it installs a function, because it makes changes to the shell itself. Which is also why running `$MAMBA_EXE` doesn't work, if the var contains the path to the external executable. So, you said _"if I change line 8 from `micromamba activate ${env_name}` to `${MAMBA_EXE} activate ${env_name}`"_, but is there some reason to make that change? If it works with `micromamba`, and that looks better, then shouldn't that do?

Comment: Though noting there's some autocompletion related stuff there, I don't think a Bash script can install those into your fish shell (if I got it right that your interactive shell is fish, but the tool here is in Bash). Well, as you note, I'm not that familiar with direnv or micromamba, even if I know something about the shell, so feel free to ignore me if I'm completely lost...

Comment: direnv comes with a fish hook which runs when fish starts: `direnv hook fish | source` which creates functions (`__direnv_export_eval --on-event fish_prompt` and `__direnv_export_eval_2 --on-event fish_preexec`) that translate the bash code to fish.

Comment: The idea behind using `$MAMBA_EXE` is that it allows more flexibility.  For example, where `$MAMBA_EXE` is defined, one could instead identify the location of similar executables like `conda`, `mamba` and of course `micromamba`, define `$MAMBA_EXE` using some rule and then proceeding to the remainder of `.direnvrc`.